# Lower class or low class?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing the following sentence and do not know whether I should use lower class or low class:
The argument of Serving in Florida is that ---- class life is a dehumanized form of existence.

I will take suggestions that are synonyms to low class.

Comment: Studying this book must be a homework assignment, given the number of questions associated with it recently. The students involved may find better help at the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site. There, you may get assistance, including on how to navigate a dictionary and a thesaurus.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is receiving downvotes, it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Could you give some context for what 'serving in Florida' is?

Comment: The answer is lower. Although id probably say 'life for the lower classes is...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower class is a generally neutral term that refers to socioeconomic status (poor). It contrasts with middle class and upper class (rich).  Quoth the OED:

> **A.** *n.*  A class of society or social grouping considered to have the lowest social status; (in sing. and pl., with *the*) the members of such a class
> **B.** *adj.* Usu. with hyphen. Of, belonging to, or characteristic of the lower class

Low class is an insulting term describing something as lacking class (culture). It contrasts with high class (refined, cultured).  The OED includes it as a transparent formulation from *low*, providing the following examples of its usage:

- *The dogged, sulky, bribe-demanding scowl, too commonly encountered from our own **low-class** officials of the Custom-house.*
- *You ain't nothing but a low-class hoe Natalie... You don't have no style*

These meanings obviously derive from the A.9/A.16c definitions that the OED has:

> **A.9.** Of lowly position in a social scale; of humble rank, position, or background; without status. In later use chiefly applied to a person's class, status, etc., and overlapping with sense **A.12c**
>
> **A.12.** With depreciative connotation **c.** Characterized by a lack of good breeding; coarse, vulgar; not socially respectable.

This last one has a specific citation where low is used with class:

- *The premises were the habitual resort of a low class of person and were frequently the scene of disorderly and disgraceful proceedings.*

Comment: Could you provide some references for this?

Comment: @dwjohnston I can't copy and paste it on my phone, but both are in the OED.

Comment: @dwjohnston references are now included